# Images won't attach to social media sharing buttons

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, share, social-networking

I have a page where I share to various social media. Pinterest works, but none of my other share buttons attach the appropriate image.

```
    <!-- Start Social Share Buttons -->
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div class="site-social">
            <div class="menu-social-container">
                <ul id="menu-social" class="nav-menu-social">
                    Share:&nbsp;
                    <li id="menu-item-816" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-816"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.suitshare.com/listing/{{listing|get:"_id"}}" target="_blank">facebook</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-816" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-816"><a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=I%20just%20found%20something%20really%20cool%20on%20Suit%20Share!%20http://www.suitshare.com/listing/{{listing|get:"_id"}}" target="_blank">twitter</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-817" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-817"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.suitshare.com/listing/{{listing|get:"_id"}}&title=I just found something really cool on Suit Share! http://www.suitshare.com/listing/{{listing|get:"_id"}}&summary=Find your perfect suit today.&source=Suit Share&image={{listing.feature_image}}" target="_blank">linkedin</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-817" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-817"><a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.suitshare.com/listing/{{listing|get:"_id"}}&media={{listing.feature_image}}&description=I found something cool on Suit Share! Check it out: http://www.suitshare.com/listing/{{listing|get:"_id"}}" target="_blank">pinterest</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-816" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-816"><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.suitshare.com/listing/{{listing|get:"_id"}}" target="_blank">google</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-817" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-817"><a href="mailto:?&subject=I just found something really cool on Suit Share!" target="_blank">email</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Social Share Buttons -->
```

**My Facebook meta:**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="I just found something really cool on Suit Share!" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Suit Share">
<meta property="og:description" content="Find your perfect suit today." />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{listing_feature.item}}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1589455891307488" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://suitshare.com/listing/{{listing|get:"_id"}}" />
```

Comment: Hmm, I really want to help you but can't from what you've shared. First, your problem, if I understand it correctly - are you trying to share a post on Facebook and the image in og:image meta tag does not display proper value? If so, it would be great to see how you get the value, are you sure it is correct? You have not described what happens instead of attaching the appropriate image. Is this of any help? http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app. Secondly, I was not sure how the HTML code relates to your problem.

Comment: But I have noticed a couple things in that - id attribute stands for Unique Identifier (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), so really use every id just once. The HTML was very hard to read as well, too much code inline and fairly long class names. That is just regarding the style though.

Comment: @LubosMenus I'm definitely retrieving the image properly. It works on Pinterest. I've fixed up the IDs, but that didn't do anything. I think it's a server thing. {{listing_feature.item}} is a django tag, so the crawler probably doesn't even see it. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Even if I add a hard-coded URL into the og image property tag for Facebook, I still don't get an attached image. I'm running on my local machine using Django. Would that have anything to do with it? Strange that Pinterest actually picks up the image though.

Comment: Oh, I probably can't help further mate, no experience in Django. Running locally shouldn't have to do anything with it since you are connected to the Internet and one of the images displays.